# paintComponent inside a JScrollbar

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, paintcomponent

I am trying out the JScrollPane for a project I am working on, and I noticed a problem.  When the frame with the drawing is first invoked, the drawings inside look fine.  However, the moment I scroll using the scrollbar, the drawings "overlap" each other and it messes up the whole thing.  Now I thought this was because my project was complicated, so I tried to do it in a much simpler way.  I ended up with the same result.  I attached the codes (for the simple version), as well as pictures forthe moment it becomes an error:

The Jpanel class, where I do the drawing:

```
entepublic class PaintThis extends JPanel {

public PaintThis()
{
    setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
}



public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics)
{
    graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
graphics.fillOval(0, 0, 30, 30);
graphics.drawOval(0, 50, 30, 30);       
graphics.fillRect(50, 0, 30, 30);
graphics.drawRect(50, 50, 30, 30);

} }
```

The class where I draw the frame:

```
public class CreatePanel {

public CreatePanel()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(new PaintThis());
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(scroll);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
} }
```

And just the main file:

```
public class theTest {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    CreatePanel panel = new CreatePanel();
}}
```

Now these are the images that result:

Initial image (when I start the program)

[image: InitialImage]

When I scroll

[image]

When I go back to the original position

[image]

Thank you very, very much for any help that you can give.  I have been stuck here for almost a week now, and I really tried to look for the solution myself.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

You need to call the super's method in the override: `super.paintComponent(g);`. This will allow the JPanel to do its housekeeping including erasing previous images.

```
@Override
proteced void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.setColor(Color.RED);
  g.fillOval(0, 0, 30, 30);
  g.drawOval(0, 50, 30, 30);       
  g.fillRect(50, 0, 30, 30);
  g.drawRect(50, 50, 30, 30);
}
```

Comment: @peeskillet: sorry. and thanks for reminding me about protected. `@Override` too.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I did not realize that that is an essential part of it.  A week's worth of looking at code and one line answers it.  I'm such an idiot.  Thanks again!

Comment: @PaoloPapa: You're not an idiot as there's nothing intuitive about graphics program (at least to me), and so it requires learning new rules. Best of luck!

Comment: @PaoloPapa if the proposed solution worked, then please click on the green checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally frame.setVisible(true) should be after     frame.add(scroll);

```
frame.add(scroll);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Additionally call the super constructor in the JPanel Intialization.

```
public PaintThis()
{
    super();
    setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
}
```

Comment: @peeskillet: His answer appears to be in addition to mine. 1+ to this answer for good advice.

Comment: @peeskillet agreed. those were just additional recommendations that I wanted to add to the code.